# How could this function be re-written using Underscore.js library?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, underscore.js

Need to do some data transformation for this object:

```js
let states = [{
    "status": "up",
    "timefrom": 1551271539,
    "timeto": 1551284429
  },
  {
    "status": "down",
    "timefrom": 1551284429,
    "timeto": 1551284489
  },
  {
    "status": "up",
    "timefrom": 1551284489,
    "timeto": 1551294149
  },
  {
    "status": "down",
    "timefrom": 1551294149,
    "timeto": 1551294269
  },
  {
    "status": "up",
    "timefrom": 1551294269,
    "timeto": 1551876329
  }
]

let newStates = states.map(state => {
  let obj = {};
  obj[state.status] = [state.timefrom, state.timeto];
  return obj;
})

console.log(newStates);
```

My goal is to return an array of objects where the object is something like {up: [1551271539, 1551284429]}

Comment: why use underscore when that appears to work fine?

Comment: you don't need underscore for this, your solution will suffice.

Comment: I need this in Underscore.js because the service that I need to import this data can ONLY be modified with Underscore.js, hence the question...

Answer (score 0):

using underscore you can write the same thing as below:

```js
let states = [{
    "status": "up",
    "timefrom": 1551271539,
    "timeto": 1551284429
  },
  {
    "status": "down",
    "timefrom": 1551284429,
    "timeto": 1551284489
  },
  {
    "status": "up",
    "timefrom": 1551284489,
    "timeto": 1551294149
  },
  {
    "status": "down",
    "timefrom": 1551294149,
    "timeto": 1551294269
  },
  {
    "status": "up",
    "timefrom": 1551294269,
    "timeto": 1551876329
  }
]

let newStates  = _.map(states, (state) => {
  const obj = new Object();
  obj[state.status] = [state.timefrom, state.timeto];
  return obj;
})

console.log(newStates)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.9.1/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

It's basically the same thing that you have in the question, just wrapped inside `_.map` function

Answer (score 0):

@nircraft's way is good enough, but this should help too. Check your console after running the snippet.

```js
let states = [{
    "status": "up",
    "timefrom": 1551271539,
    "timeto": 1551284429
  },
  {
    "status": "down",
    "timefrom": 1551284429,
    "timeto": 1551284489
  },
  {
    "status": "up",
    "timefrom": 1551284489,
    "timeto": 1551294149
  },
  {
    "status": "down",
    "timefrom": 1551294149,
    "timeto": 1551294269
  },
  {
    "status": "up",
    "timefrom": 1551294269,
    "timeto": 1551876329
  }
]

let newStates = [];
_.each(states, (state) => {
  if(state.status === "up") {
    var timeFrom = state.timefrom;
    var timeTo = state.timeto;
    newStates.push({up: [timeFrom, timeTo]});
  }
  else{
    var timeFrom = state.timefrom;
    var timeTo = state.timeto;
    newStates.push({down: [timeFrom, timeTo]});
  }
})

console.log(newStates);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.9.1/underscore-min.js"></script>
```